# setting up a command switching between \flushleft and \flushright environments

Tags: environments

I'm trying to make code formatting a conversation between two ends with boxes left and  right respectively. So far i have seen examples in which two `\NewEnviron` were used respectively for left side boxes and right ones.

I'd like to make a single `\newcommand` that will decide on the basis of a parameter value whether it should be `\begin{flushleft}` or `\begin{flushright}`

here is my non-working try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newcommand{\bubble}[3]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\flushright}}{\begin{\flushright}}{\begin{\flushleft}}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.5\textwidth, title=#2]
       #3
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\flushright}}{\end{\flushright}}{\end{\flushleft}}

% use it like this:
\bubble{flushleft}{friend}{hello, what's your plan today?}
\bubble{flushright}{me}{nothing!}
```

Comment: There are a few issues in your code. With `\newcommand` you have to give the name of the macro with a leading backslash, so it should be `\newcommand\bubbles...`. Whereas in `\begin` you should not use a leading backslash, so correct would be `\begin{flushright}` or `\begin{flushleft}`, same for `\end`. Is the title in `#2` to be always the same for the same alignment? How do you intend to use `\bubbles`? Can you show a (non-)working minimal example how you intend to use it?

Comment: for the backslash before "bubbles" it's a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give the first parameter to `\bubbles` without backslash, you can just use it as parameter to `\begin`. This simplifies the command a lot, with no test being necessary.

I suppose `varwidth` is to be used somewhere else, because for this simple example it isn't necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\bubbles}[3]{%
  \begin{#1}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.5\textwidth, title=#2]
       #3
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{#1}
}

\begin{document}

Test

\bubbles{flushleft}{Title Left}{Contents left\\\lipsum[1][1-2]}

\bubbles{flushright}{Title Right}{Contents right\\\lipsum[1][3-4]}

More text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i left \usepackage{varwidth} in the example here because i was not sure whether \textwidth was part of it.

Comment: `\textwidth` is standard LaTeX.

Comment: without additional options what would be the simplest way to make left boxes with title and content right aligned, and right boxes left aligned? Nothing justified!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a much simpler syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\bubble}[3]{%
  \begin{flushleft}
  \if>#1\hspace*{\fill}\fi
  \mbox{\begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.5\textwidth, title=#2]
    #3
  \end{tcolorbox}}%
  \end{flushleft}
}

\begin{document}

\bubble{<}{friend}{hello, what's your plan today?}
\bubble{>}{me}{nothing!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same title and alignment for each speaker, it might be a better idea to store that information inside a key you can use as the first mandatory argument to `\bubble`. I added an optional argument to `\bubble` with which individual customizations can be made.

The following does so using `expkv-def` for a key=value interface (of course other packages could be used for this as well).

The `box` key can be used to forward additional keys to the `tcolorbox` environment (in the example I use this to specify colours for each speaker).

The `align` key might take the value `center` in which case a `center` environment is used, else the used environment will be `flush<align>`, so `right` and `left` are possible values.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{expkv-def}

\makeatletter
% we define new keys here. The `store' type of keys will store the value during
% its usage inside the macros. The `code' type allows own definitions. We use it
% to define a key that will add additional contents to an existing macro
% (\bubble@box) with a comma between the old and new material.
% With `initial' we set initial values for the keys `width` and `align`, all
% other macros are initially empty (title and box).
% The `BOX' key will overwrite any other option passed to `tcolorbox', whereas
% the `box' key will add to the list of options.
\ekvdefinekeys{bubbles}
  {
     store title = \bubble@title
    ,store align = \bubble@align
    ,store BOX   = \bubble@box
    ,code  box   = \edef\bubble@box{\unexpanded\expandafter{\bubble@box,#1}}
    ,store width = \bubble@wd
    ,initial width = .5\textwidth
    ,initial align = left
  }
% we define a shorthand macro to set options of bubbles.
\ekvsetdef\bubbleoptions{bubbles}
% the real macro
\newcommand\bubble[3][]
  {%
    % contain the definitions done by the key=value interface inside a group so
    % that one call can't affect another one.
    \begingroup
      % test if the macro holding defaults exists, if so call it 
      \ifcsname bubble@defaults@\detokenize{#2}\endcsname
        \csname bubble@defaults@\detokenize{#2}\endcsname
      \fi
      % parse the additional options with our key=value interface
      \bubbleoptions{#1}%
      % handle the `center' alignment by comparing the current alignment with a
      % temporary macro
      \def\bubble@tmp{center}%
      \begin{\ifx\bubble@tmp\bubble@align\else flush\fi\bubble@align}
        % expand the contents of `\bubble@box' so that the key=value interface
        % of tcolorbox can do its job
        \expandafter\bubble@startbox\expandafter{\bubble@box}%
          #3%
        \end{tcolorbox}%
      \end{\ifx\bubble@tmp\bubble@align\else flush\fi\bubble@align}
    \endgroup
  }
% helper macro to expand the contents of `\bubble@box' before calling
% `tcolorbox'.
\newcommand\bubble@startbox[1]
  {%
    % check if the title is empty, if so, don't use the title key of tcolorbox.
    \ifx\bubble@title\@empty
      \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\bubble@wd, #1]
    \else
      \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\bubble@wd, title=\bubble@title, #1]
    \fi
  }
% define a default option list. The optional argument is used as is for the
% `tcolorbox' options, the rest is parsed by our key=value interface. Since we
% use it inside of `\edef' the values passed to the keys here are fully
% expanded. This shouldn't be an issue normally.
\newcommand\bubbledef[3][]
  {%
    \expandafter\edef\csname bubble@defaults@\detokenize{#2}\endcsname
      {\unexpanded{\def\bubble@box{#1}}\bubbleoptions{#3}}%
  }
\makeatother

% define the two speakers (with short name A and B)
\bubbledef[colframe=red!50!black]{A}{title=Speaker A, align=left}
\bubbledef[colframe=green!50!black]{B}{title=Speaker B, align=right}

\usepackage{duckuments} % just for some dummy text

\begin{document}
\bubble{A}{\blindduck[-]}
\bubble{B}{\blindduck[-]}
\bubble[title=New Speaker]{}{A new speaker shows up.}
\bubble[align=center, width=.7\textwidth]{}{Another fat speaker is here.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Changes:

2021-02-23, 18:38 (UTC+1)

- added a lot of comments
- added an optional argument to `\bubbledef` to set the default `tcolorbox` options in an, imho, nicer way.
- changed the `box` key to add additional options instead of clearing the list
- added the `BOX` key (does what the `box` key did previously)

Comment: the end result looks really nice, but i don't know as much of latex. Most of your code would require a lot of homework.

Comment: @user1850133 just ask what you don't understand and I'll try to explain... :)